# json lookup list with enumeration in it

Tags: json, python-2.7

I'm currently learning python and I'm familiar (still beginner) with json

my goal is to have one json with many lookup list that could have duplicated value but different key

instead of having duplication of list, I'm trying to find a way to only have one copy and then reusing, i have made htis simple example;

```
import json

json_enum1 = '{"01" : "ab", "02" : "cd"}'
json_enum2 = '{"01" : "zz", "02" : "xx"}'

json_string = '{"val1": null, "val2": null, "val3": null}'

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
parsed_enum1 = json.loads(json_enum1)
parsed_enum2 = json.loads(json_enum2)

parsed_json['val1'] = parsed_enum1
parsed_json['val2'] = parsed_enum2
parsed_json['val3'] = parsed_enum1

print(parsed_json)    
print(parsed_json['val1']['01'])
print(parsed_json['val2']['01'])
print(parsed_json['val3']['02'])
```

result

> {u'val3': {u'02': u'cd', u'01': u'ab'}, u'val2': {u'02': u'xx', u'01':
>   u'zz'}, u'val1': {u'02': u'cd', u'01': u'ab'}}
>   ab
>   zz
>   cd

I could also do that:

```
import json

json_string = '{"val1": {"01" : "ab", "02" : "cd"}, "val2": {"01" : "zz", "02" : "xx"}, "val3": {"01" : "ab", "02" : "cd"}}'

parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)

print(parsed_json)

print(parsed_json['val1']['01'])
print(parsed_json['val2']['01'])
print(parsed_json['val3']['02'])
```

which give the same result but now if json_enum1 change, i need to change it twice

and this is a very small example, the real data is way bigger

my question is; is there a better way of doing what I'm describing/showing?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Do you just want a dict of dicts?

Comment: @jwodder yes. But I would have many duplication of dicts and i'm trying to have only 1 copy of it and reusing it.

Comment: @jwodder i also added a little bit more information in the question